# Finding Faces of Mesh Subparts

Tags: algorithm, opengl, graphics, mesh

**Description:**

I have a mesh and its all vertex-face information (vertex indices, vertex position, face indices, etc.) and I want to render sub-parts of this mesh. For example, if I have a hand mesh, I want to only render one of the fingers.

I have the information of related vertices for each sub-part which means I know vertex indices, vertex positions, etc. for the finger I want to render. However, I do not know which faces are associated with the finger. So, I need to find associated face indices to render the sub-part.

**Question:**

How I can find associated indices for sub-parts in the whole face indices set? I can use an exhaustive search algorithm but, I hope that there is a better approach, a known algorithm to do that.

**More Information:**

```
class Vertex
{
   Vertex(float _x, float _y, float _z)
   {
      x = _x; y = _y; z = _z; 
   }
   float x, y, z; // Positions
};

class Face
{
   Face(int _v1, int _v2, int _v3)
   {
      vertIndex1 = _v1; vertIndex2 = _v2; vertIndex3 = _v3; 
   }
   int vertIndex1, vertIndex2, vertIndex3; // Vertex indices
};
```

Example usage for a triangulated square mesh:

some vector such as `std::vector<Vertex> verts` and `std::vector<Face> faces`. I have `Vertex` v1(0,0,0), v2(1,0,0), v3(0,1,0), and v4(1,1,0). So corresponding `Face` objects are f1(0, 1, 2) and f2(0, 3, 4) where 0, 1, 2, and 4 are indices of `Vertex` objects in `verts` vector. As you can see, a vertex can be in different `Face`s.

Now, let's say I have a hand mesh where `verts.size()` is 6000 and `faces.size()` is 12000. However, instead of whole hand mesh, I want to render only pinky finger and I only have a set of vertex indices of pinky finger such as (345, 369, 541, ...).

So, I know which vertices I need to use, I know whole face information, and I want to find the face indices only for these given vertices.

Comment: Are the faces that you need the ones for which *all* their vertices are in the given sub-part vertex set?  The ones for which *any* vertex is in the sub-part vertex set?  Or what?  And what is the exhaustive search you're thinking of?

Comment: The information I have for the whole mesh. I have a set containing N elements for faces. However, I only need a small part of this set.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  My question is: Precisely which faces do you need?  (I'm assuming that your inputs are a set of all faces, where for each face you have a list of the vertices that make it up, as well as a subset of the vertices corresponding to the sub-part.  Given these two things, precisely what are the criteria that a given face should be part of the result set?)

Comment: I added some more context. Please check the question.

Comment: @ciyo: You still did not answer j_random_hacker's question. Namely this: if only one of a face's vertices are found in the desired vertex indices list, should that face be considered part of the desired mesh or not?

Comment: No, it should contain 3 vertices.

Comment: So we have also learnt that every face has exactly 3 vertices.  Then if there are n vertices and m faces in total, an O(m+n)-time, O(n)-space algorithm is easy: First make a "set" data structure containing all vertices in the sub-part vertex set (e.g. using a hashtable, sometimes called a "dictionary"). Then just go through every face in the list of faces, throwing out any that contain any vertex not in the hashtable.

Answer (score 1):

If the simple O(m+n)-time, O(n)-space algorithm I described in a comment is too slow, there are a variety of things you can do, but I suggest the following easy trick that will quickly find all relevant faces whenever (a) the width *or* the height *or* the depth of the bounding box containing all sub-part vertices is "small", and (b) most faces are not "too wide":

Precompute 6 lists of faces, 2 for each dimension (x, y, z): one sorted by increasing minimum vertex co-ord in that dimension, the other sorted by increasing maximum vertex co-ord in that direction.  From the given list of sub-part vertices, find the minimum and maximum position in each of the 3 dimensions (so 6 numbers, mx, my, mz, Mx, My, Mz).  Binary-search in the list of faces sorted by minimum vertex x co-ord for mx, and then again for Mx, giving positions within the list i and j, respectively.  We need only actually test the faces in the range i .. j, since every other face by definition has at least one vertex with x co-ord outside the range mx .. Mx (if its minimum x co-ord is < mx, it has at least 1 vertex outside the range; if its minimum x vertex is > Mx then all 3 vertices are outside the range).  Remember j-i, and do similarly for the other 5 sorted lists, keeping track of the one with the smallest value of j-i.  Finally, test all faces in that smallest possible list "the hard way".